# How to get the value of hidden field in <li> using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I place filname in a hidden input field in `<li>` lable, I hope to get the value of hidden input field using jQuery, but the following code don't get the correct result, it return undefined value,   how can I do? Thanks!

**Js**

```
function GetHiddle() {

    $(".ActionClass").change(function () {
        var selectValue = $('.ActionClass').val();

        var fileName = GetHiddenFilename(this.parent);
        alert("My "+fileName);

        if (selectValue == "DoDelete") {

        }

        if (selectValue == "DoRename") {

        }
    });

}



function GetHiddenFilename(obj) {
    return $(obj).siblings("input[type='hidden']").val();
}
```

**Html**

```
<ul class="ul-file">              
                    <li>
                           <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A1.PNG" />
                           <select class="ActionClass">
                             <option value="DoAction">Action</option>
                             <option value="DoDelete">Delete</option>
                             <option value="DoRename">Rename</option>
                             <option value="DoCopy">Copy</option>
                           </select>                                   

                    </li>                    
                    <li>
                           <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A2.PNG" />
                           <select class="ActionClass">
                             <option value="DoAction">Action</option>
                             <option value="DoDelete">Delete</option>
                             <option value="DoRename">Rename</option>
                             <option value="DoCopy">Copy</option>
                           </select>                                   

                    </li>                   

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows.

Use `this` instead of `this.parent` and `prev` for `siblings`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function GetHiddle() {
    $(".ActionClass").change(function() {
      var selectValue = $(this).val();

      var fileName = GetHiddenFilename(this);
      alert("My " + fileName);

      if (selectValue == "DoDelete") {

      }

      if (selectValue == "DoRename") {

      }
    });
  }
  function GetHiddenFilename(obj) {
    return $(obj).prev().val();
  }
  
  GetHiddle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul-file">
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A1.PNG" />
    <select class="ActionClass">
      <option value="DoAction">Action</option>
      <option value="DoDelete">Delete</option>
      <option value="DoRename">Rename</option>
      <option value="DoCopy">Copy</option>
     </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A2.PNG" />
    <select class="ActionClass">
      <option value="DoAction">Action</option>
      <option value="DoDelete">Delete</option>
      <option value="DoRename">Rename</option>
      <option value="DoCopy">Copy</option>
     </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong in your JavaScript.  First, you're not calling your **GetHiddle()** function (not sure if this is a typo, but I left the name as-is).  Second, using you use the **parent** function via a jQuery selector and as a method.  Finally, **siblings()** is the wrong function, since you want the descendants; **find()** is more appropriate.  Here are the fixes to make your JavaScript work.

```
function GetHiddle() {
$(".ActionClass").change(function () {
    var selectValue = $(this).val();

    var fileName = GetHiddenFilename($(this).parent());
    alert("My "+fileName);

    if (selectValue == "DoDelete") {
        // Do something
    }

    if (selectValue == "DoRename") {
        // Do something
    }
});

function GetHiddenFilename(obj) {
    return $(obj).find("input[type='hidden']").val();
}

GetHiddle();
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can  simply use this all method
>   $foo is id

alert($('input#foo').val());

alert($('input[name=zyx]').val());

alert($('input[type=hidden]').val());

alert($(':hidden#foo').val());

alert($('input:hidden[name=zyx]').val());